# Heroku R14 Errors Immediately on Restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, memory-leaks

I have a `heroku` application which has a memory leak which I can't find. As soon as I restart the application, it immediately hits 100% + RAM and spits out `R14 errors`. I have tried debugging with `oink` and don't see any specific processes that are consuming a lot of RAM. I've also looked through New Relic monitoring with no results. It is across the board the processes are slow, and that's because the application is running on disk memory because the RAM is filled up.

I also tried increasing the number of dynos for Heroku but I didn't get any better performance because each dyno filled up instantly as well.

I am using `mongoid`, but I don't think it's a DB issue because I don't have any objects instantiated on application load (but haven't been able to get `oink` to work with `mongoid`, so not certain about this).

How do I debug what the issue is if it's so low level? Let me know if I need to include anything else that's relevant to debug!

Procfile:

`web: bundle exec puma -w 3 -t 16:16 -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV`

New Relic Memory Usage:
[image: Memory Usage in New Relic]

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.12'

gem 'andand'
gem 'rack-reverse-proxy', :require => 'rack/reverse_proxy'
gem 'retina_rails'
gem 'mixpanel-ruby'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'browser'
gem 'iconv' # FIXME: What's using iconv but not depending on it?
gem 'mongoid', '~> 3.1.2'
gem 'sitemap_generator'
gem 'bson_ext'
gem 'mongoid_token', :git => 'git://github.com/thetron/mongoid_token.git', :branch => 'patch/collisions-define-method'
gem 'mongoid-app_settings'
gem 'state_machine'
gem 'devise'
gem 'cocoon'
gem 'faraday'
gem 'faraday_middleware'
gem 'multi_xml'
gem 'nullobject'
gem 'rails_admin'
gem 'high_voltage'
gem 'page_title_helper'
gem 'sidekiq', '~> 2.2.1'
gem 'autoscaler'
gem 'holidays'
gem 'masked_input-rails'
gem "steps-rails"

gem 'remote_table', github: 'seamusabshere/remote_table'
gem 'hello_sign', github: "jgarber/hello_sign"
gem 's3_direct_upload'
gem 'fog'
gem 'prawn', "= 0.12.0" # monkeypatched in initializer

group :production, :staging do
  gem "sentry-raven", :git => "https://github.com/getsentry/raven-ruby.git" # exception handling
  gem 'heroku-deflater'
  gem 'bounscale'
  gem "heroku-mongo-backup"
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'holder_rails'
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'pry-debugger'
  gem 'pry-remote'
  gem 'rb-fsevent'
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'vcr'
  gem 'thin'
end

group :test do
  gem 'email_spec'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', require: false
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.42.0'
  gem 'rubyzip', '~> 1.1'
end

group :development, :staging do
  gem 'letter_opener_web'
  gem "oink"
end

gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'font-awesome-sass-rails'
gem 'chosen-rails'
gem 'chosen-sass-bootstrap-rails', github: 'duncanparkinson/chosen-sass-bootstrap-rails' # dependency versions less stringent
#gem 'slim-rails' # wasn't working with slim 2.0.0.
gem 'slim', '>= 2.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'loadjs'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 2.1.0'
gem 'wicked'
gem 'area'
gem 'american_date'
gem 'stripe'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
#gem 'unicorn'
gem 'puma'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'

group :development do
  gem 'foreman'
  gem 'capybara-console'
end

# Docusign
gem "docusign_rest", github: "Hunter-Dolan/docusign_rest", branch: "template-custom-fields"
```

Log File:

```
2014-07-03T20:47:11.751231+00:00 app[web.1]: [2] - Gracefully shutting down workers...
2014-07-03T20:47:10.985359+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-07-03T20:47:15.816388+00:00 app[web.1]: [2] - Goodbye!
2014-07-03T20:47:16.879719+00:00 app[web.1]: [2] Puma starting in cluster mode...
2014-07-03T20:47:16.879756+00:00 app[web.1]: [2] * Version 2.6.0, codename: Pantsuit Party
2014-07-03T20:47:16.879758+00:00 app[web.1]: [2] * Min threads: 16, max threads: 16
2014-07-03T20:47:16.879760+00:00 app[web.1]: [2] * Environment: staging
2014-07-03T20:47:16.879761+00:00 app[web.1]: [2] * Process workers: 3
2014-07-03T20:47:16.879763+00:00 app[web.1]: [2] * Phased restart available
2014-07-03T20:47:16.880229+00:00 app[web.1]: [2] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:4697
2014-07-03T20:47:16.880530+00:00 app[web.1]: [2] Use Ctrl-C to stop
2014-07-03T20:47:17.334021+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-07-03T20:47:15.032318+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -w 3 -t 16:16 -p 4697 -e staging`
2014-07-03T20:47:17.263991+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2014-07-03T20:47:23.635887+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2014-07-03T20:47:23.821768+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2014-07-03T20:47:23.636332+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2014-07-03T20:47:23.822488+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2014-07-03T20:47:24.650971+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2014-07-03T20:47:24.651395+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2014-07-03T20:47:25.446267+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:25 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (13)] INFO : Starting the New Relic agent in "staging" environment.
2014-07-03T20:47:25.446364+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:25 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (13)] INFO : To prevent agent startup add a NEWRELIC_ENABLE=false environment variable or modify the "staging" section of your newrelic.yml.
2014-07-03T20:47:25.446423+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:25 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (13)] INFO : Reading configuration from config/newrelic.yml
2014-07-03T20:47:25.449056+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:25 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (13)] INFO : Enabling the Request Sampler.
2014-07-03T20:47:25.449488+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:25 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (13)] INFO : Environment: staging
2014-07-03T20:47:25.449563+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:25 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (13)] INFO : Dispatcher: puma
2014-07-03T20:47:25.449676+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:25 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (13)] INFO : Application: staging
2014-07-03T20:47:25.700934+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:25 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (13)] INFO : Installing Net instrumentation
2014-07-03T20:47:25.708768+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:25 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (13)] INFO : Installing Mongo instrumentation
2014-07-03T20:47:25.717379+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:25 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (13)] INFO : Installing deferred Rack instrumentation
2014-07-03T20:47:25.717785+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:25 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (13)] INFO : Installing Rails 3.1/3.2 view instrumentation
2014-07-03T20:47:25.717913+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:25 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (13)] INFO : Installing Rails3 Error instrumentation
2014-07-03T20:47:25.717993+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:25 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (13)] INFO : Finished instrumentation
2014-07-03T20:47:25.778682+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:25 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (9)] INFO : Starting the New Relic agent in "staging" environment.
2014-07-03T20:47:25.778783+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:25 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (9)] INFO : To prevent agent startup add a NEWRELIC_ENABLE=false environment variable or modify the "staging" section of your newrelic.yml.
2014-07-03T20:47:25.778837+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:25 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (9)] INFO : Reading configuration from config/newrelic.yml
2014-07-03T20:47:25.783896+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:25 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (9)] INFO : Enabling the Request Sampler.
2014-07-03T20:47:25.706445+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:25 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (13)] INFO : Installing middleware-based Excon instrumentation
2014-07-03T20:47:25.715460+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:25 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (13)] INFO : Installing Sidekiq instrumentation
2014-07-03T20:47:25.717602+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:25 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (13)] INFO : Installing Rails 3 Controller instrumentation
2014-07-03T20:47:25.784780+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:25 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (9)] INFO : Environment: staging
2014-07-03T20:47:25.784874+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:25 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (9)] INFO : Dispatcher: puma
2014-07-03T20:47:25.784990+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:25 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (9)] INFO : Application: staging
2014-07-03T20:47:26.038988+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:26 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (9)] INFO : Installing Net instrumentation
2014-07-03T20:47:26.049103+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:26 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (9)] INFO : Installing Mongo instrumentation
2014-07-03T20:47:26.059261+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:26 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (9)] INFO : Installing deferred Rack instrumentation
2014-07-03T20:47:26.059684+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:26 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (9)] INFO : Installing Rails 3.1/3.2 view instrumentation
2014-07-03T20:47:26.059879+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:26 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (9)] INFO : Installing Rails3 Error instrumentation
2014-07-03T20:47:26.060018+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:26 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (9)] INFO : Finished instrumentation
2014-07-03T20:47:26.045499+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:26 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (9)] INFO : Installing middleware-based Excon instrumentation
2014-07-03T20:47:26.059020+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:26 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (9)] INFO : Installing Sidekiq instrumentation
2014-07-03T20:47:26.059466+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:26 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (9)] INFO : Installing Rails 3 Controller instrumentation
2014-07-03T20:47:26.368273+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:26 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (13)] INFO : Reporting to: https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/677464/applications/3061766
2014-07-03T20:47:26.458487+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:26 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (5)] INFO : Environment: staging
2014-07-03T20:47:26.458578+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:26 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (5)] INFO : Dispatcher: puma
2014-07-03T20:47:26.458581+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:26 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (5)] INFO : Application: staging
2014-07-03T20:47:26.548922+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:26 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (9)] INFO : Reporting to: https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/677464/applications/3061766
2014-07-03T20:47:26.455500+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:26 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (5)] INFO : Starting the New Relic agent in "staging" environment.
2014-07-03T20:47:26.455631+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:26 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (5)] INFO : To prevent agent startup add a NEWRELIC_ENABLE=false environment variable or modify the "staging" section of your newrelic.yml.
2014-07-03T20:47:26.455717+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:26 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (5)] INFO : Reading configuration from config/newrelic.yml
2014-07-03T20:47:26.458187+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:26 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (5)] INFO : Enabling the Request Sampler.
2014-07-03T20:47:26.668916+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:26 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (5)] INFO : Installing Net instrumentation
2014-07-03T20:47:26.688577+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:26 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (5)] INFO : Installing Mongo instrumentation
2014-07-03T20:47:26.681101+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:26 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (5)] INFO : Installing middleware-based Excon instrumentation
2014-07-03T20:47:26.705940+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:26 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (5)] INFO : Installing Sidekiq instrumentation
2014-07-03T20:47:26.708413+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:26 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (5)] INFO : Installing deferred Rack instrumentation
2014-07-03T20:47:26.708421+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:26 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (5)] INFO : Installing Rails 3 Controller instrumentation
2014-07-03T20:47:26.708423+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:26 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (5)] INFO : Installing Rails 3.1/3.2 view instrumentation
2014-07-03T20:47:26.708424+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:26 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (5)] INFO : Installing Rails3 Error instrumentation
2014-07-03T20:47:26.708426+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:26 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (5)] INFO : Finished instrumentation
2014-07-03T20:47:27.370289+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:27 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (5)] INFO : Reporting to: https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/677464/applications/3061766
2014-07-03T20:47:27.582068+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [Raven] Raven 0.4.8 ready to catch errors
2014-07-03T20:47:28.393745+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [Raven] Raven 0.4.8 ready to catch errors
2014-07-03T20:47:29.305090+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [Raven] Raven 0.4.8 ready to catch errors
2014-07-03T20:47:30.534618+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.12874609.85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b sample#memory_total=513.47MB sample#memory_rss=511.88MB sample#memory_cache=0.00MB sample#memory_swap=1.59MB sample#memory_pgpgin=136551pages sample#memory_pgpgout=5511pages
2014-07-03T20:47:30.535205+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=513M(100.3%)
2014-07-03T20:47:30.535457+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2014-07-03T20:47:32.487456+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:32 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (9)] INFO : Doing deferred dependency-detection before Rack startup
2014-07-03T20:47:32.845196+00:00 app[web.1]: [2] - Worker 9 booted, phase: 0
2014-07-03T20:47:33.253529+00:00 app[web.1]: Started HEAD "/" for 54.247.188.179 at 2014-07-03 16:47:33 -0400
2014-07-03T20:47:33.482376+00:00 app[web.1]: [2] - Worker 5 booted, phase: 0
2014-07-03T20:47:33.481842+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:33 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (5)] INFO : Doing deferred dependency-detection before Rack startup
2014-07-03T20:47:34.059295+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path="/" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=64d068d2-a4dc-44d4-874d-d0a2fc233157 fwd="54.247.188.179" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=14817ms status=200 bytes=1150
2014-07-03T20:47:33.870224+00:00 app[web.1]: Jul 03 16:47:33 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b rails[9]: Oink Action: home#index
2014-07-03T20:47:33.969379+00:00 app[web.1]: Jul 03 16:47:33 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b rails[9]: Memory usage: 406532 | PID: 9
2014-07-03T20:47:33.969419+00:00 app[web.1]: Jul 03 16:47:33 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b rails[9]: Oink Log Entry Complete
2014-07-03T20:47:34.055371+00:00 app[web.1]: b74e646e-7e55-448f-814d-e36eedc44ea9{"format_ver":0,"datetime":"2014-07-03 16:47:34 -0400","data":[{"name":"cpu","value":419.99999999999835},{"name":"memory","value":184.875},{"name":"busyness","value":0},{"name":"throughput","value":0}],"framework_ver":"Rails 3.2.14"}4a061908-db52-4224-ad4b-9850a47c7edf
2014-07-03T20:47:36.243895+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path="/" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=02655c94-7288-482e-bd20-ca77837e64b4 fwd="54.247.188.179" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=301 bytes=167
2014-07-03T20:47:41.730828+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path="/" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=f7f58e72-ee99-445c-97a0-2ede3eabfe0d fwd="50.31.164.139" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=249ms status=301 bytes=167
2014-07-03T20:47:41.965324+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][07/03/14 16:47:41 -0400 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b (13)] INFO : Doing deferred dependency-detection before Rack startup
2014-07-03T20:47:41.966048+00:00 app[web.1]: [2] - Worker 13 booted, phase: 0
2014-07-03T20:47:46.318773+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path="/" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=ab9072f3-145e-4f3d-b524-7ff98a64ee4c fwd="54.251.34.67" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=23ms status=301 bytes=167
2014-07-03T20:47:49.403750+00:00 app[web.1]: Started HEAD "/" for 50.112.95.211 at 2014-07-03 16:47:49 -0400
2014-07-03T20:47:49.987482+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path="/" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=97e23913-fa7f-48a6-90a3-861bdf07be9d fwd="50.112.95.211" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=601ms status=200 bytes=1149
2014-07-03T20:47:49.825456+00:00 app[web.1]: Jul 03 16:47:49 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b rails[13]: Oink Action: home#index
2014-07-03T20:47:49.910239+00:00 app[web.1]: Jul 03 16:47:49 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b rails[13]: Memory usage: 472088 | PID: 13
2014-07-03T20:47:49.910300+00:00 app[web.1]: Jul 03 16:47:49 85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b rails[13]: Oink Log Entry Complete
2014-07-03T20:47:49.983950+00:00 app[web.1]: b74e646e-7e55-448f-814d-e36eedc44ea9{"format_ver":0,"datetime":"2014-07-03 16:47:49 -0400","data":[{"name":"cpu","value":379.999999999999},{"name":"memory","value":179.828125},{"name":"busyness","value":0},{"name":"throughput","value":0}],"framework_ver":"Rails 3.2.14"}4a061908-db52-4224-ad4b-9850a47c7edf
2014-07-03T20:47:50.238718+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.12874609.85ab02a7-2014-4901-9350-f39a9724e11b sample#memory_total=552.01MB sample#memory_rss=511.59MB sample#memory_cache=0.00MB sample#memory_swap=40.42MB sample#memory_pgpgin=155493pages sample#memory_pgpgout=24526pages
2014-07-03T20:47:50.239253+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=552M(107.8%)
2014-07-03T20:47:50.239467+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

---Update: # of Object Instances----

Running the below gives me the instances of `strings`, and various other objects. I think the number of `strings` is too high, but I can't find info on how to dive into what is creating the strings.

```
ObjectSpace.each_object.with_object(Hash.new(0)){ |obj, h|
  h[obj.class] += 1
}.select{
|k,v| puts "#{k} => #{v}" if k == String || k == Array || k == Hash}

String => 689832
Array => 78652
Hash => 3390
```

Comment: Do you have anything which may be running at Rails initialize? If you're getting these problems when you immediately load the Rails application, it might be an issue within your Rails setup itself?

Comment: Yeah, this is basically what it was (with the server setup).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tons of debugging and trying different things, I eventually found the issue was with the server configuration. My `Procfile` used to read:

`web: bundle exec puma -w 3 -t 16:16 -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV`

Which maximized the threads to 16, with 3 workers. I updated it after reading [this article](http://blog.codeship.io/2013/10/16/unleash-the-puma-on-heroku.html). I'm going to do more debugging to see what performs the best, but already this is a huge increase in performance.

`web: bundle exec puma -t ${PUMA_MIN_THREADS:-8}:${PUMA_MAX_THREADS:-12} -w ${PUMA_WORKERS:-2} -p $PORT -e ${RACK_ENV:-development}`